# Divisibility of dimension by matrix equations.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let ${\bf M}$ and ${\bf N}$ be two real $k\times k$ matrices such that ${\bf M}^2+{\bf N}^2={\bf M}{\bf N}$. Show that if $\det\left({\bf N}{\bf M}-{\bf M}{\bf N}\right)\neq 0$, then $3\mid k$.

Comment: I guess it's vacuously true if $M=N$, so you can disregard the question in parentheses.

Comment: @ChristopherCarlHeckman I tried working with $\left({\bf M}+{\bf N}\right)^2$ and somehow relate it to ${\bf NM}-{\bf MN}$, but it was quite unsuccessful.

Comment: I looks to me like if $M^2+N^2=MN$ then $M$ and $N$ must commute so $MN-NM=0$ so the situation in which its determinant is non-zero never arises.

Comment: @WW1 : What's your reasoning? ... @ Luckyluck63 : The conclusion suggests that you might need to look at $(M+N)^3$ or $(M-N)^3$.

Comment: the r.h.s. of $M^2+N^2=MN$ is invariant under interchange of $M$ and $N$  so the l.h.s. must also be invariant thus $MN = NM$

Comment: @WW1 : That's not valid reasoning. You can have, for instance, $MN=0$ but $NM\not=0$. ($M=\pmatrix{1&1\cr 0&0\cr}$ and $N=\pmatrix{-1&1\cr 1&-1\cr}$, for instance.)

Comment: $$M^3+MN^2 = M(M^2+N^2) = M\cdot MN = (M^2)N = (MN-N^2)N = MN^2-N^3,$$ so $M^3=-N^3$. I feel this is close, but it's not a complete answer.

Comment: @ChristopherCarlHeckman great. If you compute ${\bf 0} = \left({\bf M}^3+{\bf N}^3\right)^2 = {\bf M}^6 + {\bf N}^6 + {\bf M}^3{\bf N}^3 + {\bf N}^3{\bf M}^3 = {\bf M}^6 - {\bf N}^6$, hence ${\bf M}^6 = {\bf N}^6$. Inductively, we can prove that ${\bf M}^{6k} = {\bf N}^{6k}$ and ${\bf M}^{6k+3} = -{\bf N}^{6k+3}$. However, we have not used the second formula yet.

Comment: The fact that we haven't done so suggests we look expanding $(NM-MN)(???)$ for appropriate ???. If you get $0$, then you know that $???=0$. ... I'm going to go offline for a while. (BTW, you can get $M^6=N^6$ by squaring both sides of $M^3=-N^3$.)

Comment: Random thought ... There was a problem in the American Mathematical Monthly within the past couple of decades which involved determinants, and whose proof ended up proving that some dimension was a multiple of 3. It might be vaguely relevant.

Comment: The reason why it seemed familiar is that I submitted a solution to that other problem. You can check out the problem and its solution at https://math.la.asu.edu/~checkman/AMM/matrices.pdf . A similar (but more general) problem showed up in Crux Mathematicorum at https://cms.math.ca/crux/v31/n8/page549-569.pdf (you want to look at #2998, on page 567). I don't see an obvious solution based on your condition ($M^2+N^2=MN$), but I'll keep working.

Comment: @ChristopherCarlHeckman The first link seems to give us the answer. I think we need to let ${\bf A} = {\bf M} + \omega{\bf N}$, for $\omega=\frac{-1}{2}+\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}$. Right?

Comment: I would think you let $A=M+iN$ in these problems, but you can try that. ... I also wanted to update you; I found out that $(M-N)^2=-NM$, proof by expansion.